# My knockout form is not preventing the event to bubble, thereby submitting the form "for real"

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

I have this code in html.

```
<form method="POST" data-bind="submit: submitComment">
    <label for="comment">
        <textarea name="comment" data-bind="value: commentTextArea"></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </label>
</form>
```

and this is my knockout viewmodel

```
this.commentTextArea = ko.observable('');
this.submitComment = function(formElement) {
    alert("I'm being posted!");
    return false;
}
```

My problem is that when I submit the form the `return false;` row is ignored, thus submittinig the form "for real". I can verify that I am in the `submitComment()` method since the alert is fired.

I've read the knockout guide and several examples but no example even say I would need the `return false;` line.

The goal is to prevent the event from bubble. Thanks

Comment: try formElement.preventDefault();

Comment: @MujeebuRahman, hi, i'm getting Uncaught TypeError: formElement.preventDefault is not a function

Comment: try this.preventDefault();

Comment: The form should not get submitted "for real", as `knockout` calls `preventDefault` on the event object under the hood. However, it indeed does bubble, and there's no current way to turn it off. I'll open a ticket for making `knockout` use a `submitBubble` binding, just as inside the `event` binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by changing the data-bind-type to an event like this

```
<form method="POST" data-bind="event: { submit: submitComment }">
    <label for="comment">
        <textarea name="comment" data-bind="value: commentTextArea"></textarea>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </label>
</form>
```

By changing to an event I get the `event`-parameter that I use to stop propagating like this

```
this.commentTextArea = ko.observable('');
this.submitComment = function(formElement, event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
}
```